# HTMLPurifier removing <a name="#someanchorname"></a> - how to stop this from happening?

Tags: anchor, htmlpurifier

Using htmlpurifier 4.10, anchor name tags are being stripped out of text.

Current config:

```
    $class_file         = 'static/htmlpurifier-4.10.0-lite/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
    $class_html_cleaner = 'HTMLPurifier';
    require_once($class_file);

    // Initiate config 
    $config     = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', FALSE);
    $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', TRUE);
    $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp', TRUE);

    // initiate class
    $purifier   = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    // clean passed HTML
    $html       = $purifier->purify($html);
```

Adding the config `HTML.Allowed`:

```
    $config->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', FALSE);
    $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', TRUE);
    $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp', TRUE);
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|target|name|id|class]');
```

Does nothing, the name tags are still removed.

Removing three `AutoFormat` options so I just have this:

```
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|target|name|id|class]');
```

Also strips the `name` attribute, but at least now the name tag I posted is returned as `<a></a>`.

What else am I missing here?  I'd rather not use HTML.Allowed if it means I have to explicitly state every *other* potential tag/attribute I would ever use.

Guidance/help greatly appreciated.  Been fighting with this for an hour now.

Comment: I’ve never used it, but two things to check. Is it removing the tag because it doesn’t contain any text content? And is it removing the name attribute because it’s use is deprecated on a tags? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a Scroll down for obsolete tags.

Comment: I tried using attribute `id` and at least now, it's just stripping that and returning `<a></a>`.

Comment: Check the Attr.EnableID rule. It looks like it removes ids by default. Again, I’ve never used it. Just looking at the documentation.

Comment: Thank you kind user, that did the trick.  If you care to submit this as an answer, I'll gladly accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attr.EnableID rule removes html id attributes by default.  (And it looks like name attributes as well.)
http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.EnableAttrID

Why it happens is explained here, http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-id.html.